# Jackson Deserialize List of Objects into a Map

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-modules, jackson-databind

I have my own custom deserializer

```
@Override
public Map<String, Car<?, ?>> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    JsonNode carsNode = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
    Map<String, Car<?, ?>> CarsMap = new HashMap<String, Car<?, ?>>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    for (JsonNode node : carsNode) {
        CarsMap.put(node.get("name").asText(), mapper.readValue(node.asText(), Car.class));
    }
    return CarsMap;
}
```

Thought this doesn't work because `Car` is a base class and the map should have Map String, SubClasses of Cars)

> Input JSON = [{"name": "honda", "type": "Regular , "speed": 60}]

this should be in map such as `Map.put("honda", RegularCar.class)`

Comment: I just wondering why you don't deserialize to list of car and then in separate method/class transform it to map?

Comment: @Pulkownik I'm actually having trouble deserializng the car  "mapper.readValue(node.asText(), Car.class)" this doen't seem to work

Comment: how your car class look like? Do you use @JsonDeserialize ?

Comment: @Pulkownik very simple if I  desrielaize using the actual type example

mapper.readvalue(data, regularcar.class) that works but it doesn't work with base class

mapper.readValue (data, car.class)

Comment: Ok so you should read here http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/05/jackson-json-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-of-subclasses-of-an-abstract-class/ hot to deal with subclasses in jackson.

Answer (score 2):

You may annotate base `Car` class to tell Jackson which subclasses to instantiate according to the value of `"type"` field in JSON. For example if you have `RegularCar` and `ClassicCar` extending `Car`.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RegularCar.class, name = "Regular"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ClassicCar.class, name = "Classic")
})
class Car {
```

This would allow you to parse like this:

```
String json = "{\"name\": \"honda\", \"type\": \"Regular , \"speed\": 60}";
Car car = mapper.readValue(json, Car.class);
```

where `Car car` actually points to a `RegularCar` instance. Since the container is declared as `Map<String, Car<?, ?>> CarsMap` this is exactly what you want to `put` there and then cast appropriately what you `get` from the `Map`.

Comment: I'd like to do this without annotation because then I'm tightly coupled with Jackson

Comment: @user3100209 you can replace `@JsonSubTypes` by `Module` that registeres subtypes programmatically. You can also use "mix-in annotations" to associate `@JsonTypeInfo` with  base class, without adding it directly into that class.